# Getting error when trying to remove multiple directories

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a script to automate removing directories of closed support cases I handle. I think I have a working solution, though I am sure the code could be prettier. It's ugly as I am not a developer:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil

cases_dir = input("Please enter your files directory: ")
cases_list = os.listdir(cases_dir)
for name in cases_list:
    print(name, sep='\n')

open_cases = pd.read_csv(r"cases.csv")
open_cases.columns = ["Number", "Product", "Subject", "Customer Contact", "Customer Name", "State", "Internal Status", "Follow up", "Case Priority", "Updated", "Updated by", "Days open"]
open_cases = open_cases[["Number"]]
print(open_cases, sep="\n")

list_a = cases_list
list_b = open_cases
x = (set(list_a)-set(list_b))
print(sorted(x)))
shutil.rmtree(x, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)
```

I get a case listing from both and I deleted the print statements for brevity. Here is the error in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/myproject/extract_cases.py", line 25, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(x, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 506, in rmtree
    if os.path.islink(path):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 231, in islink
    st = os.lstat(path)
TypeError: lstat: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ``shutil.rmtree`` removes *one* directory tree. What makes you think it can remove *several* at once? You already know how to do something for each item in a container, what specific issue do you have doing ``shutil.rmtree`` for each item in the set?

Comment: I want to remove all the folders of closed cases. I thought creating a list of directories that could be iterated over so I could safely delete the data in them. And my research showed that shutil.rmtree was the tool for the job. Please correct me if I am wrong in that assumption. Please note I am not a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shutil.rmtree` waits `string`, `bytes` or `os.PathLike` types but your `x` variable is a `set`.

You can iterate through on your `set` object with a `for` loop. You can see an example below.

**Code:**

```
x = set(list_a)-set(list_b)
print(sorted(x))
for path in x:
    shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)
```

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a list. Sets are iterable.

Comment: Thanks for your notice. You are right. It was my fault. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the updates. I have modified my script to use the for loop and still getting errors:

Comment: Still getting errors: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'CS0135890' that is the 10 directory in the list. And I should have mentioned that I am using the folder names, with out data in them on my test system. Before trying it out on my live system.

Comment: Your `FileNotFoundError` is not related to type error. It seems the paths are not correct in your `x` variable. Perhaps if you print the paths before removing can help you debug it (`print(path)` in the `for` loop before `shutil.rmtree()`).

Comment: Interestingly after doing a print(path), it gave me a listing of directories. Which I sorted in the for loop: for path in sorted(x) I am still getting the error about dir not found. It does occur to me, being the python newbie, that the full path is not being used. Is that right?

Comment: It depends on that. I recommend to use full path because in that case the Python 100% to find the directories. If the path is not full then the current location matters. I mean it matter where you call the Python script from. you can check the "current location" with `print(os.getcwd())`